# Quiero pasar este codigo Mysql a Django como puedo hacerlo?

Tags: python, django

Hola alguien que me ayude quiero pasar este codigo a Django y Python como puedo hacerlo.

```
SELECT `clasificador`, SUM(`total`) AS t_total FROM clasificacion
GROUP BY `clasificador`
```

Les agradecería mucho su ayudad.

Comment: MySQL es un sistema de gestión de BBDD mientras que Python es un lenguaje de programación y Django es un framework web hecho en Python. No es equivalente una consulta SQL a lo que pides. Modifica la pregunta aportando más detalles o será cerrado.

Comment: GRACIAS PERO YA PUDE SOLUCIONARLO :D

Answer (score 2):

Para convertir la consulta SQL que quieres, debes usar las funciones de agregación de Django. Y ya que vas a agruparlos, debes usar la función `annotate`.

Esta una forma de hacerlo.

```
from django.db.models import Sum

query = Clasificacion.objects\
            .annotate(t_total=Sum(total))\
            .values('clasificador', 't_total')
```

Al usar `annotate` aplicar la función `Sum`, el lugar donde se encuentra la clausula `values()` impacta en la forma en la que se genera la consulta.

Puedes consultar la documentación aquí: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-values-clauses.